# JQuery Tab: Dynamic Add Tab causes page reload

Tags: jquery, tabs

I had implemented click a link which dynamic adding a tab but causes the whole page get reload. Is there anyone know what is the reason?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var tabObj = $("#tabs").tabs({
 add: function(event, ui) {
             //select newely opened tab
             tabObj.tabs('select',ui.index);

         }, collapsible: true, cache: true});
 // , fx: {opacity: "toggle", duration: "normal"}

 //Dynamic add tab
 $("#assignee").click(function(){
 //alert("FFFFFFFF");
 tabObj.tabs("add", "#noc","NOC");
 //tabObj.tabs("select", "#noc"); 
 }); 

});
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `return false;` after `tabObj.tabs("add", "#noc","NOC");`

That should hopefully work. Not tested.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#assignee").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    tabObj.tabs("add", "#noc","NOC");

});
```